# Since update to org-mode 9.4 misaligned column view headers

Tags: org-mode, formatting, column

I updated org-mode to 9.4. When I enter column view, the header is not in the correct size, so table columns are not below the respective header field.

I use different font sizes for different org-heading levels. But untill now in column-view everything was just the same font. Now it seems as if the lines inherit their respective org-level font size.

What does cause this and how can I make it return to normal proportions?

Answer (score 2):

Got it:

the faces `org-column` and `org-column-title` had no font and size set. After setting it to a Monospace font, the columns align.

But I'm sure, it worked before without specifying. Don't know what changed.