# misaligned column view headers

Tags: org-mode, align

Similar topic here [Since update to org-mode 9.4 misaligned column view headers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62963/since-update-to-org-mode-9-4-misaligned-column-view-headers)

I read that headers are using faces: org-column and org-column-title. Can I just delete those faces? I don't need them in headers, just normal text & alignment.

[image]

Comment: In order for the alignment to work, both the header line and the text have to use a fixed-width font (most probably the *same* fixed-width font - different fonts are not guaranteed to have the same width, even if they are both fixed-width). Other than that, the faces are immaterial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-column nil
                    :inherit 'default)
```

solution from
https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/14058